# I want to set the page as default url which is not in the root folder

Tags: asp.net

How can i set it in web config file?

below is the code which i have tried but it is not working..

`

```
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <add value="~/Account/Login.aspx"/>
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>`
```

i want login page as default page for my site. that means if my site url is www.mysite.com then it should open my login page. i can able to set any page in root directory, but when i try to set the login.aspx page from Account which is a sub folder in the solution i am not able to set

please help.

Comment: which version of IIS you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for redirection - not a default document.

defaultDocument is for picking which file within a folder should be executed when the folder is requested. Having a value of a subfolder there is probably not wokring.

My suggestion would be to add a default.aspx file in the root folder and make it redirect to the page you want.

Comment: thank you for reply, i want login page as default page for my site. that means if my site url is  www.mysite.com then it should open my login page. i can able to set any page in root directory, but when i try to set the login.aspx page from Account which is a sub folder in the solution i am not able to set

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the following link

http://www.serverintellect.com/support/windowsserver2008/Default-document-IIS7.aspx
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument